# Wrap JavaScript file in order to intercept outgoing requests

Tags: javascript, proxy, wrapper, sandbox

I have got a **JavaScript file** (extremely obfuscated) on my site that handles videos.

And this JavaScript file requests another JavaScript file and that JavaScript file calls another and so on....

Can I wrap the first JavaScript file (maybe sandbox it) so any request for external resource will be redirect through my proxy?

I mean if the JavaScript file call:

http://example.com/another.js

After I will intercept the call it will be:

http://myproxy.com/?url=http://example.com/another.js.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the js file calls the next one, By using an xhr request or by adding a script tag to the dom ... ?